# Compare three files based on columns using Perl

Tags: perl, text-processing

I have three files, and I need to match the first column of file 1 to the first column of file 2 and then match the second column of file 1 with the first column of file 3.

file 1:
fji01dde AIDJFMGKG
dlp02sle VMCFIJGM
cmr03lsp CKEIFJ
and so on...

file 2:
fji01dde 25 30
dlp02sle 40 50
cmr03lsp 60 70
and so on...

file 3:
AIDJFMGKG
CKEIFJ

output needs to be:
fji01dde AIDJFMGKG 25 30
cmr03lsp CKEIFJ 60 70
and so on...

I only want lines that are common in all three files.

The below code results in the following output:
AIDJFMGKG
CKEIFJ
fji01dde 25
dlp02sle 40
cmr03lsp 60

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %data;

while (<>) {  
    my ( $key, $value ) = split;  
    push( @{ $data{$key} }, $value );  
}  

foreach my $key ( sort keys %data ) {  
    if ( @{ $data{$key} } >= @ARGV ) {  
    print join( "\t", $key, @{ $data{$key} } ), "\n";  
    }  
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the lines always expected to be in the same order in files 1 and 2? Files 1 and 3

Comment: Will any of the columns you are matching have duplicate values?

Comment: Each row in all 3 files is unique, but there are some repeated values in the 2nd column of file 1 and in the 2nd and 3rd columns of file 2.

Comment: The lines in files 1 and 2 are in the same order, but not file 3.

Comment: Cross posted: [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1145998) and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238462/compare-three-files-based-on-columns-using-perl)

Answer (score 0):

OK, looking at it - your problem is with that `split` - because by default, it splits on whitespace. Your second file has 3 fields by that yardstick, not two.

But also - you're not actually crossreferecing the same things, so your `while ( <> ) {` loop isn't going to do the trick.

- In file 1 - you want to check for the *value*.
- In file2, you're checking the key (and appending the values).
- In file3, you have no value, just a key.

So with that in mind:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#read file1 into a hash - but invert is it's value => key instead:
#          'CKEIFJ' => 'cmr03lsp',
# etc.  
open( my $file1, '<', "file1.txt" ) or die $!;
my %file1_content = map { reverse split } <$file1>;
close($file1);

print Dumper \%file1_content;

#read file 2 - read keys, store the values. 
#split _2_ fields, so we keep both numbers as a substring:
#e.g.:
#          'cmr03lsp' => '60 70
#',

open( my $file2, '<', "file2.txt" ) or die $!;
my %file2_content = map { split( " ", $_, 2 ) } <$file2>;
close($file2);

print Dumper \%file2_content;    

#then iterate file 3, checking if:
#file1 has a matching 'key' (but inverted - as a value) 
#file2 has a cross reference. 
open( my $file3, '<', "file3.txt" ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$file3> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if (    $file1_content{$line}
        and $file2_content{ $file1_content{$line} } )
    {
        print
            "$file1_content{$line} $line $file2_content{$file1_content{$line}}";
    }
}
close($file3);
```

This prints (excluding the "dumper" output):

```
fji01dde AIDJFMGKG 25 30
cmr03lsp CKEIFJ 60 70
```

> When I run this code, I get an error message: "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at line 10." Also, the columns in these files are separated by tabs.

Not with that sample data you don't. But yes - if your first file has more than two words per line, this will happen.

You can unroll that loop into a while loop:

```
while ( <$file1> ) { 
    my @fields = split; 
    warn "Too many fields on line $. \n" if @fields > 2; 
    $file1_data{$fields[1]} = $fields[0];
}
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error message: "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at line 10."  Also, the columns in these files are separated by tabs.

Comment: OK. That means in your first file, you have an odd number of elements. It probably means your file one isn't just two words per line. This does work with the sample data you gave though. Tab shouldn't matter, as I am whitespace splitting. You can split on \t instead though.